# Showing $\frac1{ab+4}+\frac1{ac+4}+\frac1{ad+4}+\frac1{bc+4}+\frac1{bd+4}+\frac1{cd+4}\geq\frac65$, for positive $a,b,c,d$ with $ab+bc+cd+da=4$

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Let us take $a\geq b\geq c\geq d>0$ such that $ab+bc+cd+da=4$. Show that $$\frac{1}{ab+4}+\frac{1}{ac+4}+\frac{1}{ad+4}+\frac{1}{bc+4}+\frac{1}{bd+4}+\frac{1}{cd+4}\geq\frac{6}{5}$$

- $a+b+c+d \ge 4$, $abcd \le 1$( are obvious)

I wasn't able to solve it using the following:

- using inequality of means.
- Using rearrangement inequality
- Substituting $\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't help since $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+4x}$ is concave.

Comment: - $a+b+c+d\geq 4, abcd\leq1$
- mean doesn't helped me
- rearrangement doesn't helped me
- subs $\cfrac{1}{x}, ..., $ doesn't helped me because $f(x)=\cfrac{x}{1+4x}$ is concave

Comment: $1/(1+4x)$ is convex.

Comment: @Mathlearner can you confirm that my edits are what you meant in the comments?

Comment: $\cfrac{1}{1+4x}$ is convex, but can't rearrange with $xy,xz,xt,yz,yt,zt$

Comment: always stuck on $\sum ab\leq 6$ which is not true. There is a refined path though.

Comment: @Mathlearner $ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd$ can be near $8$. For example, $(a, b, c, d) = (6474991/90162, 1/18, 1/18, 1/10000)$, we have $ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd =64833320081/8114580000 \approx 7.989732073$.

Comment: @River Li of course, $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$ isn't always lower than 6.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof.**

We have $ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd \le 4$.
(*Note*: $ac + bd \le ab + bc \le 4$.)

Let $x = ab, y = bc, z = cd, u = da, v = ac, w = bd$.
Then $x, y, z, u, v, w \le 4$, and $x + y + z + u = 4$.

We have
$$\frac{1}{x + 4} = \frac25 - \frac{1}{25}(x + 4) + \frac{(x - 1)^2}{25(x + 4)}
\ge \frac25 - \frac{1}{25}(x + 4) + \frac{(x - 1)^2}{25(4 + 4)}.$$
(*Note*: $\frac25 - \frac{1}{25}(x + 4)$ is the first order Taylor approximation of $\frac{1}{x+4}$ around $x = 1$.)
Similarly, we deal with $\frac{1}{y + 4}$ etc.

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{12}{5} - \frac{1}{25}(x + y + z + u + v + w + 24)\\[6pt]
 &\quad + \frac{(x - 1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2 + (u-1)^2 + (v-1)^2 + (w-1)^2 }{25(4 + 4)}\\
 \ge{}& \frac65,
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{27}{100} - \frac{1}{20}(x + y + z + u) + \frac{1}{200}(x^2 + z^2) + \frac{1}{200}(y^2 + u^2) \\[6pt]
 &\quad - \frac{1}{20}(v + w) + \frac{1}{200}(v^2 + w^2)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0,
\end{align*}
or (using $xz = yu = vw = abcd$)
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{27}{100} - \frac{1}{20}(x + y + z + u) + \frac{1}{200}(x + z)^2 + \frac{1}{200}(y + u)^2 \\[6pt]
 &\quad - \frac{1}{20}(v + w) + \frac{1}{200}(v + w)^2 - \frac{3}{100}abcd\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Using $abcd \le \frac{1}{4}(ad + bc)^2 = \frac{1}{4}(y + u)^2$, and
\begin{align*}
 &- \frac{1}{20}(v + w) + \frac{1}{200}(v + w)^2
 - \left(- \frac{1}{20}(x + z) + \frac{1}{200}(x + z)^2\right)\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{1}{200}(x + z - v - w)(10 - x - z - v - w)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
(using $x + z - v - w = (a - c)(b - d) \ge 0$ and $x + z \le 4$), from (1), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{27}{100} - \frac{1}{20}(x + y + z + u) + \frac{1}{200}(x + z)^2 + \frac{1}{200}(y + u)^2 \\[6pt]
 &\quad - \frac{1}{20}(x + z) + \frac{1}{200}(x + z)^2 - \frac{3}{100}\cdot \frac{(y + u)^2}{4}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
or (using $(x + z) + (y + u) = 4$)
$$\frac{3}{400}(x + z - 2)^2 \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.

Comment: I guess it is possible to use Lagrange multiplier now? since now it is all polynomial terms.

Comment: @Yimin My idea is quite complicated. Perhaps there is simple solution for the OP.

Comment: Is there a solution without so much algebraic manipulation?

Comment: @DS Hope to see a simple solution!

Comment: thanks, mate. I'm looking for that solution. This ineq is a beautiful one, for me.